# Pull large data from Neo4j Graph into Spark (Graphx or GraphFrame) to do some analysis on the graph

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, graph-algorithm, graphframes

I am working with a large graph (3M nodes and 1B relations between the nodes). I have two type of nodes, categories and users.
I want to use spark to analyze the graph data to perform path analysis between categories for example.

But I have the following inquires if anyone can help with these:

1) Do I need to load the whole graph to do the analysis on spark? So I tried to load the nodes list and edges into spark `graphframes` using the following scala code

```
val nodesQuery="match (n:category) RETURN id(n) as id,n.userid as user_id,n.catid as cat_id limit UNION ALL MATCH (n:user) RETURN id(n) as id,n.userid as user_id,n.catid as cat_id limit"
val relsQuery="match (p:category) optional match (p:category)-[r]-(n:user) return id(p) as src,id(n)  as dst, type(r) as value  val graphFrame = neo.nodes(nodesQuery,Map.empty).rels(relsQuery,Map.empty).loadGraphFrame"
```

The first issue with this I get null values for the users nodes in nodes list also a memory overflow occurs, any suggestions on this?

The reason I decided to use `GraphFrames` because the queries are supposedly optimized  but with RDDs I can load data in batches

3) What are the possible suggestions to perform distance analysis on this data (I need to measure distance between 2 categories) with a cypher code like the following:

```
MATCH path=(cat1:category{catid:'1900'}) -[rel1:INTERESTED_IN] -(user1:user) -[rel2:INTERESTED_IN*2..3] -(cat2:category{catid:'1700'}) return cat1,path,cat2,rel1
```

4)  will using Message passing via `AggregateMessages` help? Would I still need to load the whole graph into spark?